# Firebase Bind and Unbind from State in React when using Re-base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, synchronization, state

When using the [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) module with Firebase & React, I'm having some problems with React and the way to get the content from Firebase across the app.

I have two components/"pages"  and

In home I just "post" a comment, and show comment just posted and counter of how many comments have been posted. And in comments I want to show all comments posted.

I'm adding comments from Home to firebase and Its working...

```
var base = Rebase.createClass('https://my-app.firebaseio.com/');

componentDidMount : function() {

    base.bindToState('comments' , {

      context : this, 
      state : 'comments',

    });
```

This is totally working I can "post" comments to the firebase and Sync them. The problem comes when I go from Home to Comments and then come back, I'm getting this error.

```
Endpoint (comments) already has listener bindToState
```

I have tried this:

```
componentWillUnmount: function() {

 base.removeBinding('comments');    


},
```

But is not working. Is this not the right way of doing it maybe in React, am I missing something. I will appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on the documentation here https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base, your code should be...

```
this.commentsRef = base.bindToState('comments' , {
   context : this, 
   state : 'comments',
});
```

And...

```
componentWillUnmount(){
  base.removeBinding(this.commentsRef);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I totally missed it. And believe me I was like 3 days already with it :( I finally can move on.... :D